# pcdrcui.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, dll

I keep getting this error message on my Lenovo Thinkpad T400 running Windows 7 Ultimate:

[image: Error]

As far as I can tell, aside from showing this error, nothing is wrong with the system. It doesn't pop up when I'm doing anything specific, and usually is showing on my screen when I go back to my computer after being away from it for a while (such as overnight).

Any idea what this error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pcdrcui.exe is a PC Doctor software that is running in the background and is trying to fix something, but the dll is not the correct version or as suggested by Wil, the program is poorly written, try to update the PC Doctor software, or disable it.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me figure out this is probably caused by my Lenovo toolbox software.  I'll uninstall/reinstall (or leave it off) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: After uninstalling the Lenovo toolbox, I haven't seen this issue again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a program/script is calling a procedure in a DLL file that does not exist.

Basically it is either a software conflict (different version of a DLL file installed than expected) or just a poorly written piece of software - either way, it is doubtful that it is your fault - you can try reinstalling the software.

If you or anyone else is interested, a .DLL file or .EXE file is pretty similar - it just contains a bunch of subroutines and programming instructions.

The main difference between a .DLL and a .EXE is a .EXE is designed to start at a set instruction each time it is run and then call upon further instructions from itself or other files, where as, a DLL file just contains a bunch of instructions and no main entry point.

In this example, `pcdrcui.exe` is trying to call the `SymGetUnwindInfo` entry point/instruction out of the `dbhhelp.dll` file which does not exist.